# React Lazy and prefetching

Tags: reactjs, browser, lazy-loading, chunks, prefetch

I'm little lost on some things.

In my React application, I'm using `import { lazy } from 'react'` for certain large components. As I understand, this splits the code and only downloads it to the client when explicitly requested, right?

I've also come across the term "browser prefetching," but what's the difference between these two techniques?

If the browser can prefetch JS, what's the difference compared to lazy loading?

Can someone break down these concepts and explain them to me? It's a bit confusing.

Thanks in advance !!